# Find the identifier of a certain data set in firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm searching through clients invoices

These invoices are stored within the client json.

so...

```
clients: {
   ... : {
      invoices: {
      },
   },
}
```

I'm doing this by this:

```
    var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/clients/'+client+'/invoices/');
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        var list = snapshot.val();
        angular.forEach(list, function(item) {
            if(item.settings.number == id)
            {
                console.log(item.id());
                invoice.details = item;
            }
        })
    });
```

Inside the "if" how do I get the unique id auto generated by Firebase? In your html your able to do `$id` typically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you call `snapshot.val()`, you're just dealing with a Javascript object. See the documentation for [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach). You just need to specify a second argument to the function.

```
angular.forEach(list, function(item, key) {
    ...
});
```